# calender extender not showing full in div

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, css

I have one calender extender in div which i am showing on popup.

When i click the image, for calender extender, it is not viewing properly.

Its viewing as below:

[image]

I used z-index for this purpose, but it also not worked.

I tried this:

Inside script:

```
function calendarShown(sender, args) {
        sender._popupBehavior._element.style.zIndex = 1000;
    }
```

In div:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeaderEditFollowDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" ImageUrl="../images/calendar.gif" runat="server" />
                    <ajaxtoolkit:calendarextender id="CalendarExtender4" runat="server" cssclass="cal_Theme1"
                       OnClientShown="calendarShown" popupbuttonid="ImageButton3" targetcontrolid="txtHeaderEditFollowDate" animated="False">
                </ajaxtoolkit:calendarextender>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **css class**

```
calender= positon:absolute
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to check your css class for calendarextender "cal_Theme1". If there's no specifications about size, give a height or min-height value.